# Why was the "first Monday in December" originally chosen as the default meeting date for Congress?

Tags: united-states, us-congress, us-constitution

The original Constitution of the United States did not explicitly specify many dates, but one was the default date for which Congress was required to meet:

> The Congress shall assemble at least once in every Year, and such Meeting shall be on the **first Monday in December**, unless they shall by Law appoint a different Day.
>
> [Article I, Section 4, Clause 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_2:_Sessions_of_Congress)

**Why was this particular original date chosen?**

Note that Clause 1 of the same section left the date of Congressional *elections* to be determined by state and federal laws, rather than an explicit date written into the Constitution (see [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/53990/21921)).  In turn, the date that was eventually chosen for these elections then influenced the writing of the [20th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution), which set a new default date for Congress to assemble (January 3rd).  But how was the *original* date chosen?

Answer (score 6):

According to [senate.gov](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/minute/First_Monday_in_December.htm)

> When should Congress begin its annual session? The 18th-century framers of the United States Constitution, accustomed to an agriculturally based economy with its cycles of planting, growing, and harvesting, considered the mostly dormant month of December to be a particularly good time for senators and representatives to begin their legislative sessions.

Comment: Was this reasoning an entirely new idea with the Constitution, or was there already precedent among the state legislatures or the Articles of Confederation Congress?